# Counting how many times one specific value changed to another specific value in order of date range and grouped by ID

Tags: sql, zoho

I have a table like below where I need to query a count of how many times each ID went from specifically 'Waste Sale' in one value to 'On Stop' in the very next value based on ascending date and if there are no instances of this, the count will be 0

| ID | Stage name | Stage Changed Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Waste Sale | 06-05-2022 |
| 1 | On Stop | 08-06-2022 |
| 1 | Cancelled | 09-02-2022 |
| 2 | Waste Sale | 06-05-2022 |
| 2 | On Stop | 07-05-2022 |
| 2 | Waste Sale | 08-06-2022 |
| 2 | On Stop | 10-07-2022 |
| 3 | Cancelled | 10-07-2022 |
| 3 | On Stop | 11-07-2022 |

The result I would be looking for based on the above table would be something like this:

| ID | Count of 'Waste Sales to On Stops' |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 |

ID 1 having a count of 1 because there was one instance of 'Waste Sale' changing to 'On Stop' in the very next value based on date range

ID 3 having a count of 0 because even though the stage name changed to 'On Stop' the previous value based on date range wasn't 'Waste Sale'.

I have a hunch I would have to use something like LEAD() and GROUP BY/ ORDER BY but since I'm so new to SQL would really appreciate some help on the specific syntax and coding. Any version of SQL is okay.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: If there's a ID 3 as well, with no "Waste Sales to On Stops" at all, do you still want (3, 0) to be returned?

Comment: @jarlh yes, that would be perfect. Will add that to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: *"Any version of SQL is okay."* -- this kinda dangerous, there are tons different functions on different sql implementation (e.g. `to_date` on oracle and `str_to_date` on mysql). though, if you are on codility test or something, anything sure works. anyway, what you have tried?

Comment: @BagusTesa using an analytical software that supports most forms of SQL, but you are right should try to narrow it down.

Comment: @JosephHampton you should dig if we have existing tag for your software in particular, we have [tag:sisense] for example. so that relevant (experienced people) on that software be aware of your question. you can mention the software name on question title too.

Comment: @BagusTesa thank you for that, added a relevant tag for Zoho.  As for what code I have been using it would be many variations of trying the LEAD OVER and ORDER BY functions, for example: `SELECT t."Count of 'Waste Sales to On Stops'", t."ID"
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ((t."Stage Name"  = 'Waste Sale' ) AND ((t."Stage Name") OVER (ORDER BY t."Stage Changed Date" ASC) = 'On Stop' )) AS "Count of 'Waste Sales to On Stops'"
  FROM
t
group by  t."ID"
) t` most of the time when entering code like this there will be a multitude of errors relating to syntax due to unfamiliarity with these functions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use window function `lead` to take a peek at the next value of the query result.

```
select distinct id,
   (
     select count(*)
     from
     (
       select *,
              lead(stage_name)
              over(
                partition by id
                order by stage_changed_date)
              as stage_next
       from sales s2
     ) s3
     where s3.id = s1.id
       and s3.stage_name = 'waste sale'
       and s3.stage_next = 'on stop'
   ) as count_of_waste_sales_to_on_stop
from sales s1
order by id;
```

Query above uses `lead(stage_name) over(partition by id order by stage_changed_date)` to get the next `stage_name` in the query result while segregating it by id and order it based on `stage_changed_date`. Check [the query on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGNLsSRNbX4VYLpNoauGRs/0).

Note:

- I have no experience in [zoho](/questions/tagged/zoho), so i'm unsure if the query will 100% works or not. They said it supported [ansi-sql](/questions/tagged/ansi-sql), however there might some differences with MySQL due to [reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization).
- The column names are not the exact same with op question due to testing only done using DB Fiddle.
- There might better query out there waiting to be written.

Comment: Switched around a few names and it worked perfectly, it I had 15 rep I would upvote this in a heart beat, thanks so much for taking the time to answer this and describe what its doing, lifesaver!

Comment: @JosephHampton glad of help. in a hindsight, instead of subquery, i believe using `left join` and use `case` to replace nulls with 0 might run better. oh, well.